# Objective-C: Need help tracking previously pressed button

Tags: objective-c, pointers, uibutton

I was hoping you could help answer an Objective-C based question for me that is currently stopping me continuing in my program.

I have a game where you have a grid of buttons title 1, 2, 3, etc. Each of those buttons takes you to a GameScreen UIView passing with it various pieces of information - i.e. name, age, etc. If the user answers the question correctly, he is taken back to the grid - where I now want the button that he pressed to display a tick rather than just a blank button with some text as before.

My problem is keeping track of the button that was pressed. When I go back to the main screen, I can't figure out how to say 'Change the button that I just pressed to a tick image'. All things so far have come out as (null).

When I press a button at first I use the 'if([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"1"]) to tags what information I want to pass through - which is fine but after that point when I have been through another view I lose which button has been pressed.

I could pass through a variable all the way through that's unique to each button and come up with an if then else statement to test the value of the variable (i.e. if [questionansweredcorrectly isEqualToString :@"Question1"]) but as I may have a hundred or more buttons here that's too troublesome.

I hope I have explained the situation well enough and that someone will be able to point out the method I need to use here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

In response to how I load into other views I use the following style of coding:

```
GameScreen *screen = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil]; 
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

and this is how I go to a new view - doing the same from another screen to go back to the main screen with the buttons. I don't use storyboards in this piece. Does this help clarify how I go through the views? I do not use storyboards.

Comment: how do you change, and go back to the previous view?

Comment: using navigation in application.

Comment: okay the way you do it, you should change going back to the previous view, as I mentioned'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you dismiss your first view completely. Or you reload the first view where as you should just show it again.

Not 100% on how your loading your views but I think this might help:

To show the previous view (with all the buttons) simply use this code in the view that you loaded on top of the first view:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can see how that would help actually, although in this case I'm going to need to go back two views to get to the view I need. I have never heard of this way before, only the way through how I explained in my edit. I shall give it a go and report back on if this helps though...!

Comment: Thanks SirKaydian - the problem I have is that I have three screens - GridScreen (where the buttons are) -> GameScreen (questions) -> CorrectScreen (acknowledgement of correct answer) - then from CorrectScreen I am to go back to the GridScreen. Using the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated I get back to the GameScreen which makes sense but now I cannot do that again from the GameScreen to the GridScreen - do you know how I can do this? I have a feeling once I can do this then your suggestion is going to prove correct!

Comment: Ok I used [self[presentingViewController]presentingViewController]dismiss... and I'm back to the screen I want and I think this is going to work now by tracking the right button - I will confirm in a sec!

Comment: Perform the segue to GridScreen then the segue to CorrectScreen one after another. When you dismiss CorrectScreen, GridScreen will be waiting.

Comment: I have the solution now. I used [self[presentingViewController]presentingViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated = YES]; (how correct that is for code I'm not sure) but it worked nevertheless and I was able to track also the correct sender and apply the tick where needed. Thanks to you for helping out here - I think Thomas that segues relate to storyboards right? I don't use them here. However, the solution is there now so thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Yup no problem, glad I could help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a problem of design patterns. I don't think I understand precisely how this is implemented, but here's how I'd attack this.

You have QuestionGridViewController stuffed full of buttons which each show an instance of GameScreenViewController, configured appropriately based on

1. the button tapped
2. the user.

Let's follow MVC here. You need a model class which can hold every question (and possibly have question objects to encapsulate that data).

You'll also need one to represent the user and their details.

In the viewDidLoad of the QuestionGrid, load the questions from the question model to populate the view. Ones which are already completed should have the tick mark set then.

For all these button presses, init the GameScreen with a custom initializer which takes the user object and the question object as arguments.

When the GameScreen's answer is submitted, update the question object. When the QuestionGrid is loaded again, it loads the updated question. Neither view controller has to pass any data to another.

This is the great advantage of obeying MVC – you have abstracted the data from the logic, and in doing so, saved your sanity with problems like these.

I don't know if this was quite the problem you were looking to solve, but as SirKaydian has noted, it's not particularly obvious how you are doing things. However, I hope I've shown how good application design can obviate such trivial problems.